# UItableviewCell cell reuse issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am displaying images in `scrollview` horizontally in `UItableviewCell`.

Problem is when I scroll `tableview` images got mismatched.Below is my code for reference:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

ManufacturersTableviewCustomCell * cell = (ManufacturersTableviewCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[ManufacturersTableviewCustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}


cell.scrollview.delegate = self;
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundView = [UIView new] ;
cell.selectedBackgroundView = [UIView new] ;
cell.scrollview.tag = indexPath.row;
cell.btnViewAll.tag = indexPath.row;

NSDictionary *dict ;
NSArray *aryImages;


if(isFiltered && [aryFilteredProducts count]>0){
    dict = [[aryFilteredProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"manufacturers"];
    aryImages = [[aryFilteredProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"sub_categories"];
}
else if([aryProducts count]>0){
    dict = [[aryProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"manufacturers"];
    aryImages = [[aryProducts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"sub_categories"];

}

NSString *strUppercase = [[dict valueForKey:@"manufacturers_name"] uppercaseString];
cell.lblManufacturerName.text = strUppercase;

 NSString *strImgUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",KServerUrl,[dict valueForKey:@"original_image"]];

if(![[NSURL URLWithString: strImgUrl] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    [cell.imgViewManufacturer setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImgUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"] usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

[cell.viewBorder.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor colorWithRed:234.0/255.0 green:234.0/255.0 blue:234.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
[cell.viewBorder.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];

[cell.imgViewManufacturer.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor colorWithRed:234.0/255.0 green:234.0/255.0 blue:234.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
[cell.imgViewManufacturer.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];

CGFloat contentWidth = 0;

for(int i=0;i< [aryImages count];i++)
{
    if(SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568){
        if([aryImages count] >3){
            cell.btnViewAll.hidden = NO;
        }
        else  {
            cell.btnViewAll.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
    else{
        if([aryImages count] >5){
            cell.btnViewAll.hidden = NO;
        }
        else  {
            cell.btnViewAll.hidden = YES;
        }
    }
    NSDictionary *dictImageData = [aryImages objectAtIndex:i];

    UIImageView *imgView   = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake([aryImages indexOfObject:dictImageData]*(80 + 5),0,80,80)];

    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake([aryImages indexOfObject:dictImageData]*(130 + 5),0,130,130)];
    }
     [imgView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor colorWithRed:234.0/255.0 green:234.0/255.0 blue:234.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor]];
     [imgView.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
    imgView.tag  = i;
    // add tapgesture

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapgestureImg = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
    [imgView addGestureRecognizer:tapgestureImg];

    NSString *strImgUrlSubCat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",KServerUrl,[dictImageData valueForKey:@"sub_product_img"]];

    imgView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"];

    if(![[NSURL URLWithString: strImgUrlSubCat] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
        [imgView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImgUrlSubCat ] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"] usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    }
    [cell.scrollview addSubview:imgView];

    UIView *vwBackGround = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake([aryImages indexOfObject:dictImageData]*(80 + 5), 60, 80, 20)];
    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        [vwBackGround setFrame:CGRectMake([aryImages indexOfObject:dictImageData]*(130 + 5), 90, 130, 40)];
    }
    vwBackGround.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    vwBackGround.alpha = 0.5;
    [cell.scrollview  addSubview:vwBackGround];

    UILabel *lblProductName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake([aryImages indexOfObject:dictImageData]*(80 + 5)+4, 60, 70, 20)];
    lblProductName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0];

    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        [lblProductName setFrame:CGRectMake([aryImages indexOfObject:dictImageData]*(130 + 5)+4, 90, 120, 40)];
        lblProductName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];

    }
    lblProductName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lblProductName.text  = [dictImageData valueForKey:@"sub_product_name"];
    [cell.scrollview addSubview:lblProductName];

    [cell.scrollview bringSubviewToFront:vwBackGround];
    [cell.scrollview bringSubviewToFront:lblProductName];

    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
        contentWidth += 130 + ([aryImages indexOfObject:dictImageData]==0?0:5);
    }
    else{
        contentWidth += 80 + ([aryImages indexOfObject:dictImageData]==0?0:5);

    }
}


cell.scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentWidth, cell.scrollview.frame.size.height);

return cell;
}
```

Can you please suggest how to fix this issue.

Comment: Cells, as you say, are reused. Therefore you must cover every case. Your code does not. Ask yourself what happens if the image view was already added to this cell, and now the cell is reused and your code runs.

Comment: If you are dynamically adding `UIImages` and are not using them again, clear reused cell content before adding new images. Key word in understanding `UITableviewCell` is `reused`

Comment: I added this code  if ([cell.contentView subviews]){
        for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
            if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    }
but not working.Is there anything to do

Comment: @matt thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove imageviews before adding..

solved it by adding below code in cellforrowatindexpath

```
   if ([cell.scrollview subviews]){
    for (UIView *subview in [cell.scrollview subviews]) {
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] || [subview isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]){
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```